# Error occurs when max is used in groupby of bifunction in constraint streams

Tags: optaplanner

Error occurs when max is used in groupby of BiFunction in constraint streams.
I want to get max per group.
How do I get the maximum value for each group?

```
Constraint checkScrubNurseSkill(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(NurseAssignment.class)
            .join(NurseOpeSkill.class,
                    Joiners.filtering((nurseAssignment, nurseOpeSkill) -> nurseAssignment.getOpeID() == nurseOpeSkill.getOpeID() &&
                    nurseAssignment.getNurseID() == nurseOpeSkill.getNurseID()))
            .groupBy((nurseAssignment, nurseOpeSkill) -> nurseAssignment.getOpe(),
                     (nurseAssignment, nurseOpeSkill) -> nurseAssignment.getDutyID(),
                    *max((nurseAssignment, nurseOpeSkill) -> nurseOpeSkill.getScurbOpeLevel() )
                    )*
            .filter((ope, dutyid,  max) -> max < 3)
            .penalize("Check Scrub Nurse Skill", HardSoftScore.ofHard(10));
}
```

error1: The method max(Comparator) is ambiguous for the type ○○ConstraintProvider

error2: The method getScurbOpeLevel() is undefined for the type Object

Comment: Tip: sum() worked fine. (min() and max() are errors)

sum((nurseAssignment, nurseOpeSkill) -> nurseOpeSkill.getScrubOpeLevel()) → OK、
max((nurseAssignment, nurseOpeSkill) -> nurseOpeSkill.getScrubOpeLevel()) → NG

Comment: Tip: version is 8.26.0.Final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is an ambiguous parameter of the `max()` method. Both of the following overloads of the method fit there:
`max(BiFunction<A, B, Mapped> groupValueMapping)`
`max(Comparator<A> comparator)`

which cannot be inferred from the lambda.

The issue can be worked around via casting. Have a look at the [MachineReassignmentConstraintProvider](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/main/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/machinereassignment/score/MachineReassignmentConstraintProvider.java#L181), which does exactly that.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Have been struggling from couple of hours, this way fixed my issue.